# Merging two fileds in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for "add friend" .Here is the table :-

tb_addfriend

```
id   mainUid    Uid
--------------------
1    12         8
2    8          7
3    8          2
4    4          8
```

I would like to get the firends of id=8.I tried a query like this

```
Select mainUid from tb_addfriend where mainUid=8 OR Uid=8
```

It results like this

```
mainUid
--------
12
8
8
4
```

But i need a result like this

```
-----------
12
7
2
4
```

How can it possible.

Comment: mainUid, id, uid? Will you remember what these things are when you leave this code for one week and come back to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN mainUid=8 THEN Uid ELSE mainUid END 
FROM tb_addfriend 
WHERE mainUid=8 OR Uid=8
```

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting the mainUid column as a result. But the mainUid column doesn't contain the '7' or '2' values.

You'll need to determine when you need to select the mainUid or Uid by using a CASE statement. You can then use the Uid field when mainUid field is 8.

```
SELECT 
    CASE mainUid
         WHEN 8 THEN Uid
         ELSE mainUid
    END CASE
FROM tb_addfriend 
WHERE mainUid=8 OR Uid=8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query .

```
select main from tbl_1 where main<>8 union
select uid from tbl_1 where uid<>8 order by main desc
```

You can use the [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.